# "NSURLSession sharedSession" is not kind of NSURLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, objective-c-runtime

I created category for `NSURLSession`, and then I faced a problem. In iOS 7, `[[NSURLSession sharedSession] isKindOfClass:[NSURLSession class]]` returns `NO`.

I know that `[NSURLSession sharedSession]` is returning instance of `__NSCFURLSession`, but it is not a subclass of `NSURLSession`. So, it doesn't make any sense. At compile time everyting is ok, but in runtime I get unrecognized selector exception.

How can I get around with this? Is there is any runtime magic feature, that I can use? Because

```
[[NSURLSession sharedSession] respondsToSelector:@selector(dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:)]
```

returns `YES`, and that is the only method I use in my category.

Comment: dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler: is available in NSURLSession from iOS 7.0, so, it should cause any problem to call this in iOS 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to creating an instance method in your category you could create a class method which accepts an instance of `NSURLSession`.

Assuming a category like this:

```
@interface NSURLSession (MyCategory)

- (void)doSomethingWithCompletion:(MyCompletionHandler)completionHandler;

@end
```

The replacement could be:

```
@interface NSURLSession (MyCategory)

+ (void)doSomethingWithSession:(NSURLSession *)session completion:(MyCompletionHandler)completionHandler;

@end
```

With usage as follows:

```
[NSURLSession doSomethingWithSession:[NSURLSession sharedSession]
                          completion:^{ ... }];
```